# telegram.ext CommandHandler works in personal chat but doesn't work in group chat

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have a telegram bot and I'm trying to add little "features" to it that I find useful by adding more `CommandHandler`. The new features work fine in personal chat but don't work in group chats. I am perplexed by this.

My code is something as follows

```
def func1(bot, update):
    <somecode>


def func2(bot, update, args):
    <somecode>

def error(bot, update, error):
    <errorhandler>

def newfunc(bot, update, args):
    <newcode>


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('func1', func1))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('func2', func2, pass_args=True))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('newfunc', newfunc, pass_args=True))
dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)
```

The `func1` and `func2` work fine and they were there before but the new `newfunc` does not work in group chats.

I have no idea whats causing this

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There is none. The request doesn't reach the server in case of group chats. It does in case of personal chats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I had `update.message.reply_text` as the response text in the `newfunc` code but the bot was in privacy mode.

The simple solution was to turn privacy mode off so it can access the messages